# I put executable file in startup of raspberryPi 4, when I run top command in terminal 2 process running with same name, How to avoid this problem?

Tags: linux, build, raspbian, startup

I have tried with systemd method also, using RC.Local also

I have added command to following script

```
    #!/bin/bash
    while true
    do
    sudo /home/pi/RP_code/./vehicle_sep
    done
```

Comment: Check PID and PPID of each process.

Comment: yes I have checked